# How do i use the for-loop to access certain object values from another class

Tags: loops, for-loop, arraylist

I have an arrayList of objects, and want to calculate the average height of all the objects stored in said arraylist. However I do not know how to access those values or how to store them.

Currently i have done:

```
    public class class1
{
 public double height;
 public class1(double height)
 {
  this.height = height;
 }
}

    puplic Class Class2
 {
  public ArrayList<Class1> objects;


  public Class2()
 {
  objects = new ArrayList<Class1>();
 }

  public double averageHeight()
 {
  for(int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++)
 {
   whatToDo??
 }

}
```

Hopefully this isn't as big a problem as i see it as.

Comment: What language are you coding in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java do like this:

```
public double averageHeight() {
        double avgHeight = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++)
            double height = objects.get(i).height;
            avgHeight+= height;
        }
        return avgHeight / (double)objects.size();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is Java, you can do the following if **averageHeight** is part of Class2 and you have public access to everything:

```
public double averageHeight() {
    double avgHeight = 0;
    for(Class1 o : objects) {
        avgHeight += o.height;
    }
    return avgHeight / (double)objects.size();
}
```

or

```
public double averageHeight() {
    double avgHeight = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++)
        Class1 o = objects.get(i);
        avgHeight += o.height;
    }
    return avgHeight / (double)objects.size();
}
```

Comment: as far as im concerned that should definitly work, however when i try to compile i get an error saying: 

incompatible types:  object cannot be converted to double.